# Run WebDriver with Chrome Canary?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to tell [chromedriver](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/) (the [webdriver](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webdriver/raw-file/default/webdriver-spec.html) implementation within Chrome) to use Canary, Beta or current production chrome?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can ask ChromeDriver to use a Chrome executable in a non-standard location

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome.exe");
```

On Mac OS X, this should be the actual binary, not just the app. e.g., `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`.

*[via [chromedriver Capabilities and Switches]](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)*

Comment: There was a bug that was fixed in ChromeDriver 2.6: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=612  Please update to the latest version.

Comment: The option looks like it has now been renamed to `options.setChromeBinaryPath(<PATH HERE>)` Since ChromeDriver 2.16.333243 and webdriver `2.46.1`

Answer (score 4):

And the way to do this in [theintern](http://theintern.io) is by the following config

```
capabilities: {
    'selenium-version': '2.35.0',
    'chrome': {chromeOptions: {'binary': '/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome\ Canary'}},
},
```

Also, if you're looking to configure the selenium node directly here's how to pass the configuration in:

```
{
"capabilities": [
    {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "platform": "MAC"
    },
    {
        "browserName": "chromeCanary",
        "platform": "MAC",
        "chromeOptions": {
            "binary": "/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome\ Canary"
        },
        "maxInstances": 1,
        "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "platform": "MAC"
    }
],
"configuration": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 8989,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "localhost"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It should be this Google Chrome Canary.app and not just Google Chrome.app.
Try this:

```
options.setBinary("/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```